# Heartbeats and log messages over UDP

Tags: multithreading, node.js, events, websocket, udp

I currently have a controller node process and many worker node processes.

As it stands, the clients choose a random worker to connect to. The controller is there as a cache layer to store some custom in-memory, queryable data structures. The workers connect to the controller over the websocket protocol (as it takes care of message fragmentation/variable size messages for us).

I now wish to extend this such that the workers send heartbeats (with usage statistics to facilitate load balancing) and log messages (for support) to the controller. The controller will use the statistics to tell the client which server to connect to and write the log messages into the database to make them queryable for support.

However, since websockets is built on TCP, it am thinking it may not be the best protocol to do this sort of thing and that I would be better of using UDP for this. I think I am right in saying that so long as my message is under the min-MTU on my network (one datagram), I don't have to worry about message splitting as I would with TCP...(I could be wrong!)

Obviously I can't use UDP for the cache part of the controller as it requires the reliability that TCP and therefore websockets offer. So I can either have two connections, one for the heartbeat/logging and one for the cache side of things or I can use UDP and implement some sort of reliability layer for the cache requests.

Since it would probably be simpler, I think two connections would be best here, but I would prefer to have the UDP heartbeat/logging on a separate thread making callbacks to the main thread to update which client should be connected to...

Does that make sense? Is it even possible in Node? How do the modules handle these asynchronous calls which make callbacks to the main thread to report events?

Comment: this look a little bit similar to the problem, of `TCP or UDP` as in MMORPG games, and a small research i did back then.. in the end i ended up with TCP, yes both protocol have advantages and disadvantages but when you want to make sure that client got the packet, you sacrifice speed, and a bunch of other functionality that are required to be build when you choose UDP .. and TCP has them by nature.. in your case i would use TCP for "i want to make sure parts" and UDP for "i don't care if it reaches destination part"

Comment: @GeoPhoenix - so you are suggesting multiple connections?

Comment: yes that would be an excellent choice, that's how some "heavy load" mmorpg are doing it, one example is, transmit via TCP, that a package of X bytes must are arrive, stream it via UDP, make sure you are not getting the same message over and over again via UDP, and reply via TCP that everything is fine.
Note that there are various way of mixing those two, try reading a book about networking to get more knowledge over this subject.